# Footer won't stay inside width of browser window

Tags: html, css

This is driving me nuts, but probably very simple to sort out. I can't seem to get my footer to only be 100% width of the browser screen. At the moment there is a scroll bar at the bottom so that you can scroll to see the right end of the footer.

Do I have to wrap footer in another DIV with 100% width and then give footer 100% width?

Any pointers on how to get footer to only be 100% width of the screen, and still be stuck to the bottom of the screen, would be really helpful, without giving it a fixed px width,

```
http://openstrings.co.uk/contact
```

Thanks

Comment: If you have an element of `100%` width, and `padding`, it will be larger than 100%, since padding is added inside the element, according to the `box model`.

Comment: ah yes. thanks for that. Didn't see the padding

Answer (score -2):

The problem is with id 'footer' in styles.css file, line 93.
Namely, it says: width: 100% - and that's a problem.

I've managed to fix it by adding **style="width:99%** at line 111:

```
<div id="footer" class="clearfix" style="width:99%;">"
```

However, it's better if you can fix it in css file. In Fact, this is kind of "quick-and-dirty" solution, the proper way is box-sizing.